# Computer won't POST

Tags: windows-7, laptop, boot, windows-vista

I have an HP Presario F700.

Earlier, the computer would POST and then restart and I found out it was because of a bad hard drive. I replaced the Hard Drive and installed Windows 7 on it and everything worked fine, except then I was told to install Windows Vista on it, and when I went to do that the computer wouldn't POST at all.

Now the backlight on the screen turns on, then off, then on, then off, and then the computer restarts, staying off for about 20 seconds before turning itself back on. Nothing ever comes up on the screen, just the backlight turns on and off.

What could cause a problem like this?

I already tested the new hard drive and both sticks of RAM and those aren't the problem.

Comment: If you take out the Drive and RAM, does it act the same way, or does it provide proper POST codes?  Does it behave any differently on AC than it does on Battery?  If you put it on AC and remove the battery, does it work any differently?

Comment: I don't have the battery, so it's only running on AC Power and I've tried it without the Hard Drive and RAM and it acts the same whether they're in or out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a power problem, try a known-good AC adapter.

If that doesn't fix it, it's probably the motherboard that needs replacing.

If that's the case, since that notebook is from ~2008, just buy a new notebook - it'll probably be cheaper. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty far shot solution, but it did work on a couple boxes in our shop. Unplug the laptop from AC power. With no battery in it (easy since you don't have one), hold down the power button for a ten count. Plug the laptop back into AC power and try booting again.